# how to bind another event into the close button in sweet alert2 modal in angular5

Tags: angular5, sweetalert2

I am trying to add another code while closing of sweet alert2 modal.Because while closing sweet alert2 modal,it removes the content first then only it removes the modal container.So the problem is it first showing a blank container before closing of the modal.How can I solve this issue?

**modal.component.ts**

```
<swal  #reqCallSwal (beforeOpen)="beforeOpen($event)" (open)="onOpen($event)" [showConfirmButton]="false" [showCancelButton]="false" [showCloseButton]="true" customClass="reqCallModalSwtOuter" (close)="modalReset($event)" [allowOutsideClick]="false">
  <ng-container *swalPartial>
    <!--<div class="scrollbarToggle"></div>-->
    <div id="rcyc-modal-requestCall"  *ngIf="apiResponseBStatus && apiResponseCStatus">
      <section class="content_section">
        <div class="l-container-wrapper">
          <div class="l-container intro-header leadinto">
            <div class="l-container row">
              <div *ngIf="apiResponseBStatus" class="body-copy">
                <div class="headline-block c01_D intro-header leadinto">
                  <!-- <h4 *ngIf="apiResponseB?.field_sub_header" [title]="apiresponseB?.field_sub_header | convertHtml" [innerHtml]="apiResponseB?.field_sub_header"></h4> -->
                  <h1 *ngIf="apiResponseB?.title" [title]="apiresponseB?.title | convertHtml" class="headline" [innerHtml]="apiResponseB?.title"></h1>
                </div>
                <p *ngIf="apiResponseB?.field_summery" [innerHtml]="apiResponseB?.field_summery"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="row is-10-2">
                <div class="column is-9 lead_form_right">
                  <form  id="requestCallFormId" name="requestCallForm" [formGroup]="lead_gen_form" novalidate autocomplete="false">
                    <fieldset>

                      <div class="basic-form_group lead_form_field">
                        <!-- name_sec -->
                        <div class="row is-6-6">
                          <div class="column is-6 form_fields formContainer">
                            <label class="basic-form_label form_label basic-form_label-required">First Name</label>
                            <input id="firstNameId" class="basic-form_input basic-form_input-half" type="text" formControlName="firstname" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="30">
                            <span *ngIf="!lead_gen_form.controls.firstname.valid && !fnameWhitespaceError && lead_gen_form.controls.firstname.touched" >This field is required</span>
                            <span *ngIf="fnameWhitespaceError" [innerHtml]="fnameValidationMsg"></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="column is-6 form_fields formContainer">
                            <label class="basic-form_label form_label basic-form_label-required">Last Name</label>
                            <input id="lastNameId" class="basic-form_input basic-form_input-half" type="text" formControlName="lastname" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="60">
                            <span *ngIf="!lead_gen_form.controls.lastname.valid && !lnameWhitespaceError && lead_gen_form.controls.lastname.touched" >This field is required</span>
                            <span *ngIf="lnameWhitespaceError"  [innerHtml]="lnameValidationMsg"></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- name_sec -->
                      </div>
                      </div>

                    </fieldset>
                  </form>
                  <div class="row is-6-6">
                    <!-- <p class="succ" *ngIf="succmsg">THANK YOU FOR REGISTERING</p> -->
                    <div class="column is-6">
                      <div class="row is-6-6">
                        <div class="column is-6 submit_btn">                                                
                          <input type="submit" id="submitId" (click)="leadGenSubmit()" [disabled]="lead_gen_form.invalid || zipcodereq || emailErr || countryerr || fnameWhitespaceError || lnameWhitespaceError || lead_gen_form.controls.country.value==0" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                        <div class="column is-6 clear_btn">
                          <input type="reset" id="resetId" (click)="ngOnInit()" value="Clear">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column is-6"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="apiResponseCStatus" [innerHtml]="apiResponseC.field_summery"></div>       
                </div>                              
                <div class="column is-3"></div>
              </div>
            </div>      
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

</swal>
<!-- <button (click)="modalOpen()">click</button> -->
```

in the above code I am added my angular templates into the sweet alert2 modal with the help of 'swalpartial' directive.I also changed the animation of opening and closing of modal with the help of css animation.

```
**modal.css**

div.swal2-show{
  /*-webkit-animation: fadein 1.3s;
  animation:fadein 1.3s;*/
  -webkit-animation:zoomin 0.5s ease-in;/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation:zoomin 0.5s ease-in;/* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation:zoomin 0.5s ease-in;/* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation:zoomin 0.5s ease-in;/* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation:zoomin 0.5s ease-in;
}
div.swal2-hide {
  -webkit-animation:zoomin 0.5s ease-out;
  animation:zoomout 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

the animation works nicely,but when I close the modal it gets blank and then the animation will work.I found the reason after I pass an event into the close() of sweet alert2 modal.When closing the modal it removes a div element by default whose class name is 'swal2-content' where all my modal contents are inside this div then only it removes all class related to sweet alert2.How can I prevent removing of  'swal2-content' class firstly while closing the modal?

Comment: you should include code and then explain what you want want to achieve & what you were able to achieve?

Comment: ok.i will edit my question.